# Many buttons in a mobile app

Tags: interface, actions

Imagine an app that can be native, hybrid or responsive and I have to put in the UI three actions: approve, deny and waiting for correction. Whats the best way to display these options?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that only two of those are actual actions (Approve and Deny), whereas "Waiting for correction" is more of a status. Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more details, but in general: Write something about the thing you would like to approve, and then list possible actions. If there are only 2-3 actions, buttons can do fine.

You can use the same design principles for both native apps and  responsive web designs (And with technology like Apache Cordova, you can use web-based technologies also for native apps).

If you are on a touch interface, make the buttons larger. And if you are on a narrow device (like below), put them in vertical order. If you are on a wider device, you can organise them horizontally.

And yes, "Waiting for correction" sounds more like a status. A possible action would be "Ask for corrections", which opens a dialogue where you can write *what* you like corrected, and then send back a message that whatever you received needs corrections. After this request is sent, the status in you app is also changed to "Waiting for corrections". A small button or other UI interface to show the history of the request would probably also be nice.

[image: Possible layout]